Is the Conjecture of Representing Integers as Differences of Semiprimes and Primes Extendable to Products of Distinct Primes?
Conjecture:
Let $k$ and $l$ be fixed distinct positive integers ($k≠l$). Then, for every positive integer $n$, there exist prime numbers $p_1,p_2,…,p_k∈\mathbb{P}$ and $q_1,q_2,…,q_l∈\mathbb{P}$ such that:
$$
 n=\Biggl(\prod_{j=1}^l q_j\Biggl)-\Biggl(\prod_{i=1}^k p_i\Biggl)
$$
Here, $k$ and $l$ are predetermined and fixed, meaning that for these specific values, the primes $p_i$ and $q_j$ are chosen to represent every positive integer $n$.
Specifically, we investigate cases where one of the products is a semiprime, which helps illustrate the relationship between primes and semiprimes in this context.(namely $l=2,k=1$)
Context and Motivation:
This conjecture extends classical problems of representing integers as sums or differences involving primes and semiprimes. Unlike the Goldbach conjecture, which focuses on sums of primes, this conjecture explores the representation of integers through differences of products of distinct primes. This approach could potentially uncover new patterns in the distribution of primes and semiprimes.
In related discussions on Conjecture: Every Non-Zero Integer as the Difference of a Semiprime and a Prime, it has been observed that when
$n$ is a prime number, the proportion of primes
$p<30,000$ such that
$n+p$ is semiprime remains consistently above $6$%. This suggests a persistent structural property in the relationship between primes and semiprimes, warranting further investigation into other composite classes.
Additionally, apart from the plots, we have verified that there are no counterexamples within the range of
$±10,000,000$ for
$n$ (excluding zero). Although this conjecture is limited to positive integers, swapping the roles of the subtracting and subtracted products ensures that the conjecture holds for negative integers as well. This comprehensive verification reinforces the robustness of the conjecture across a broad spectrum of integers.
Preliminary Results:
When
$n$ is a prime number, the proportion of primes
$p<30,000$ such that
$n+p$ is semiprime consistently remains above $6$%. Despite the generally low overall proportion, this threshold indicates a potential underlying pattern that could be significant in understanding the distribution of primes and semiprimes.
Experimental Approach:
I conducted computational experiments for integers
$[1,10,000]$ and primes
$N=30,000$. The results demonstrate that for prime
$n$, the proportion of primes
$p$ satisfying
$n+p$ being semiprime does not fall below $6$%, indicating a consistent pattern.
Graphical Representation:
Below are figures showing the fraction of primes
$p$ less than
$N=30,000$ for which
$n+p$ is semiprime, plotted against
$n$. The consistent proportion above $6$% suggests a potential underlying structural property.

Questions:
1.Mathematical Validity: Is this generalization mathematically valid within the context of number theory? Are there any inherent logical or structural issues with extending the conjecture in this manner?
2.Approaches for Proof or Counterexample: In seeking a proof or counterexample for this conjecture, what approaches or existing theories would be effective? Specifically, I would appreciate advice from the perspectives of additive number theory or multiplicative number theory.
■ Originality of This Conjecture
I approached this conjecture from the perspective of memory space, rooted in my background in computer science, rather than formal training in number theory. This unique viewpoint allowed me to develop and utilize two original methods:
- Subtractive Integer Theory:
In traditional additive integer theory, integers are typically expressed as the sum of other integers. However, by prioritizing subtraction, this new approach enables a broader range of integer representations, offering a fresh perspective that encompasses both even and odd, positive and negative integers.
- Classification of Composite Numbers Based on the Number of Constituent Primes:
By classifying composite numbers according to the number of constituent primes, this method allows for a more detailed analysis of the distribution and properties of semiprimes, emphasizing integers with specific prime-based structures.
“I developed this conjecture entirely on my own.”

The conjecture, as written, seems trivial to me. Let $2^\ell$ be the smallest power of $2$ that is $>n$, and $k$ the number of prime divisors (including multiplicities) of $2^\ell-n$. Then $n=2^\ell-m$ with $m$ having $k$ prime factors in its decomposition, and necessarily $k<\ell$. If the conjecture has additional requirements, it should be stated more precisely than with "Specifically..."

@YCor Thank you for your insightful feedback. I have now clarified that $k$ and $l$ are fixed and do not change during the exploration process until it is completed. If there are any other points of misunderstanding or areas for further clarification, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

It's not yet clarified, you still write confusingly "For any positive integer , there exist distinct positive integers  and ", and later say something contradicting this.

@YCor Thank you very much for your valuable feedback. I have revised the conjecture to clarify the points you raised. Specifically, I adjusted the wording to emphasize that $k$ and $l$ are fixed beforehand, and that the prime numbers are chosen accordingly to represent every positive integer $n$.

You're already up to 23 edits.  This is excessive, and needs to stop.

Apologies for the excessive edits. I understand this has been disruptive, and I will refrain from further updates.
